# How to only collect keys in a type that has an object with some specific key as a value in Typescript interface?

Tags: typescript, redux

I have a redux state like this

```js
interface DataState {
  dashboard: {
    data: DashboardData | null
    isLoading: boolean
    error: string | null
  }
  policySearch: {
    data: PolicySearchData | null
    isLoading: boolean
    error: string | null
  }
  other: {
    someKey: someValue
  }
}
```

and I have an action creator that toggles the `isLoading` state in given field in the data state

```js
toggleDataLoading('policySearch', true)
```

I don't want to send a wrong first parameter to `toggleDataLoading` function so I have this:

```js
type FieldsThatHaveLoadingState = 'dashboard' | 'policySearch
```

because some fields won't have `isLoading` state

I tried to think of a way to programmatically collect the keys from the `DataState` with Typescript. Something looks like this in javascript:

```
const keysIWant = {}
Object.keys(dataState).forEach(key => {
 if(dataState[key].isLoading) keysIWant[key] = true
})
type FieldsThatHaveLoadingState = keyof typeof keysIWant
```

Is it possible to do this kind of a collection only using Typescript types and checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach shown below correctly limits valid keys to the function call.

The complexity of having to have nested distributive conditionals to express this will hopefully go away with the work on https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23188

```js
interface DataState {
  dashboard: {
    isLoading: boolean
  }
  policySearch: {
    isLoading: boolean
  }
  other: {
    someKey: 'someValue'
  }
}

type LoadableKey<T = keyof DataState> = T extends keyof DataState ? DataState[T] extends { isLoading: boolean } ? T : never : never

const toggleDataLoading = (stateKey: LoadableKey) => {
  console.log(`Loading ${stateKey}`)
}

toggleDataLoading('dashboard');
```

Comment: Given this was hard to do without locally scoped type aliases, and there actually doesn't seem to be a nice way to do it, I raised a feature and syntax proposal for Typescript at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40194 and I am tracking https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23188 where the feature is being worked on.

Comment: Thanks so much @cefn, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great to hear it, @Ege. I managed to get it to one line in the end `type LoadableKey<T = keyof DataState> = T extends keyof DataState ? DataState[T] extends { isLoading: boolean } ? T : never : never`

Comment: This is awesome @cefn, I learned a lot just by looking at this.